# Responsive image src depending on media

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi i'am using Twitter Bootstrap 3.1.1

Is there any way to use different src for different media by using some sort of class? Hiding stuff doesn't work since the image still loads.

something like :

```
<img xs-src="images/xs_img.jpg" md-src="images/md_img.jpg" class="img-responsive" >
```

Is the only method to use javascript? Or is there something already implemented in bootstrap 3 for that kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this JavaScript Framework: [RetinaJS](http://retinajs.com/)

I've never used it but it looks nice and simple.

> **EDIT:** there is another way to do this, just define the size of the img
>   element and take the @2x graphic as source for every display, would
>   work too

Comment: thx but i don't realy use less i use scss/sass and 4kb of code for only 27 lines of code that i wrote i'll take my code instead.

Comment: Hehe just as information, Bootstrap has a lot more code than you would have if you would write the responsive design yourself ^^

Comment: I know that's why i was asking if there was something like this in twitter bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 0):

I created my own js code

Note:js code should be at the bottom of the page or else when loading the page for the first time img don't exist yet.

```
var timeout=0;
$(window).resize(function(){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout=setTimeout(function(){
        resizeWindow();
    },500);
});

function resizeWindow(){
    var windowWidth=$(window).width();
    switch(true){
        case(windowWidth<750):/* you could specify other sizes to suit your needs*/
            $("img").each(function(){
                if($(this).attr("data-xs-src")){
                    $(this).attr("src",$(this).attr("data-xs-src"))
                }
            })
        break;
        default:
            $("img").each(function(){
                if($(this).attr("data-default-src")){
                    $(this).attr("src",$(this).attr("data-default-src"))
                }
            })
    }
}
resizeWindow();//use setTimeout if js code is in header
```

Html code

```
<img data-default-src="images/img.jpg"  data-xs-src="images/xsimg.jpg" >
```

Comment: my site has not many images that should be shown differently. Only 1-2 per page so it is ok to use this method. I'm not sure if it's still ok to use this if it has lots of heavy img though.